# Confusion in Decorator Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am reading Decorator design pattern from Gof. I am having confusions at the following points

1. It says the important aspect of pattern is it lets the decorators
       appear anywhere where the component is used. Client's can't
       generally tell a difference between a decorated component or
       un-decorated component? For example, if i think, i am a client, and
       basic component is related to Email but i want it secure also.
       Someone is providing functionality to me like.

   ```
    Email email = new SecuredEmail(new TextEmail());
   ```

   Q:   This is just pretty hypothetical. Won't i as a client know
   that, this text-email is decorated? I am just confused, can someone
   clarify this doubt?
2. A decorator and its component aren't identical. A decorator acts as
   a transparent enclosure. But from an object identity point of view,
   a decorated component is not identical to the component itself.
   Hence you shouldn't rely on object identity when you use decorators.
   What does it mean?

Can someone explain these two parts.

Ben

Comment: You have piled up creation and using. These are two completely different things in patterns. During creation you have to know everything. During using you don't need that knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that the `Email` is a Java interface. Any class implementing the `Email` can be used to initialize the variable `email` including any decorator, since decorators implement an interface or extend an abstract class (implementing an interface). Clients can know what's the class instance, of course, but they usually don't need to do it. Just use `email.getClass()`.

On the other hand the decorator is not the same object as the decorated. It wraps the decorated object. Therefore the `TextEmail` and `SecuredEmail` are not the same objects. If the code looked like:

```
TextEmail txtEmail = new TextEmail();
SecuredEmail securedEmail = new SecuredEmail(txtEmail);
```

then checking their identity would give the next result:

```
System.out.println("identical: " + (txtEmail == securedEmail));
```

i.e.

```
identical: false
```

The `equals(Object)` could be written so it could give a different result, e.g.

```
System.out.println("equal: " + txtEmail.equals(securedEmail));
```

the output:

```
equal: true
```

Comment: IMHO you have violated the second statement. I do not see the reason that Text emails should be equal tot Secure Email.

Comment: Thanks @Vash - there's no reason to have these two objects equal in this case. In general it may be a case.

Comment: Thanks @Vash and Boris. So it in short means that, basically a decorator is extending an abstract class which inturn implements or extends the component interface, so they can't be idential as in case of identity?

Comment: Accepting the answer would do the job ;-)

Comment: @BorisPavlović would do right away, can you just confirm the part in my comment, if my understand is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're not the client. The code using the email is the client, and it only knows that the object is an Email. It won't know that it's a TextEmail decorated with a SecuredEmail.

As for relying on the object identity, it means that a piece of code should work the same whether it's being passed a TextEmail or the TextEmail wrapped in a SecuredEmail. In a technical sense, you shouldn't rely on `email1 == email2`, since email2 could be email1 decorated with SecureEmail.

Answer (score 1):

Ad.1 As a client, user of decorated class you can not determine what implementation do you use.

We need to assume that `Email`, is an interface and lest create two methods.

Method 1

```
 public Email getMail() {
   reutrn TextEmai();
 }
```

Method 2

```
 public Email getMail() {
   reutrn SecureEmail();
 }
```

As user of an API, you will know that there exists a class that have method `Email getMail()`, you can not determine by it description what class will be resolve. It could be Method 1 or Method 2. But as a used you can not be sure.

The second point, refer to object equality. For this example The `TextEmail` object is not equal to `SecureEmail`. As Boris Explained in his answer and comments. The decorator may but not must implement the equals method in the same way. There fore you should never trust or rely on equality when decorator pattern is used.

Comment: So it in short means that, basically a decorator is extending an abstract class which in turn implements or extends the component interface, so they can't be idential as in case of identity? Yes as Boris explained if we implement equals in a way, it might return true, but it totally depends on implementation. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: More o less yes. The decorator can extend any non final class or implements and interfaces and take as argument an instance. But finally  the point is that user (developer), you can not assume what decorator was used or trust that method equals will work in the same way for decorated object.